# Embed Youtube in HTML5 Template

Tags: html, youtube, embed

Noob here with HTML5/CSS3 Bootstrap 3.35 responsive template question about embedding YT video into blog page.

I'm trying to place the iframe snippet in the proper place for proper function. This is the HTML code.

After clicking/activating the video, I get an error page saying "file not found".

```
 <!-- blog side -->
<section class="blog-side sp-seven blog-style-one standard-post video-post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content-side">
                <div class="blog-details-content">
                    <div class="video-gallery">
                        <img src="images/news/video.jpg" alt="Awesome Video Gallery">
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <div class="icon-holder">
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <a class="html5lightbox" title="Garden Video" href="<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/NNcvbxIODsY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a> 
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not a coder but can find my way with enough guidance.

All suggestions welcomed.

The list of plugins is here

```
!--jquery js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script src="js/validation.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
```

Note the "fancybox.js" and "html5 lightbox.js"

Comment: The `href` attribute is for urls and hash ids only.

Comment: Are you just using Bootstrap? There isn't a bootstrap 3.5, and 3.4 doesn't have a lightbox. Could we see the full code please?

Comment: Bootstrap 3.35 is the CSS./*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.5 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
/*/*!! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License /*!| github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
html {/*!

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is not correctly formatted.  You need to remove the `a` tag around the `iframe`.

```
<!-- blog side -->
<section class="blog-side sp-seven blog-style-one standard-post video-post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content-side">
                <div class="blog-details-content">
                    <div class="video-gallery">
                        <img src="images/news/video.jpg" alt="Awesome Video Gallery">
                        <div class="overlay-gallery">
                            <div class="icon-holder">
                                <div class="icon">
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/NNcvbxIODsY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe><i class="fa fa-play"></i> 
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. However, removing the <a> tags got rid of the lightbox function. Still, no play of the video.